# Is there any way to accomplish the same output which is given by stdout.write(), as we can't use it on browsers in dart?

Tags: dart

```
stdout.write()
```

I mostly use this function when I don't want the newline() after message. I know about print() but with the output, it also adds newline by default. stdout.write() don't add newline but I think it can't be used on browsers, it only works on dart VM.

So please can anyone show me how to achieve the same output as stdout.write() for browser-based work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[print](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.0.0/dart-core/print.html) use `console.log` in browser so you cannot write text without newline (this behaviour is enforced by browser not Dart).

You can use a [StringBuffer](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.0.0/dart-core/StringBuffer-class.html) to append text without newline and call `print(mybuffer)` when you're ready to output your full line.